# Input and output array elements in MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, intel

Here is my MIPS code. It is supposed to input 10 integers in array and then output them. I can input integers but after entering 10 integers it doesn't output any array element.

```
.data
arr: .space 40

.text
.globl main
main:
    la $t0, arr #copying array address into $t0

    iterateForInput:
        blt $t4, 9, forLoopInput

    sub $t0, $t0, 40

    iterateForOutput:
        blt $t4, 9, forLoopOutput

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

forLoopInput:
    li $v0, 5   #input integer
    syscall
    move $t1, $v0   #moving integer into $t1
    sw $t1, ($t0)   #storing integer at array address
    add $t0, $t0, 4
    add $t4, $t4, 1
    b iterateForInput

forLoopOutput:
    lw $t6, ($t0)
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t6
    syscall
    add $t0, $t0, 4
    add $t4, $t4, 1
    b iterateForOutput
```

Comment: `forLoopInput` is an infinite loop since you haven't added any code that will ever exit the loop. Same with `forLoopOutput`.

Comment: Why tag "intel"? Did you try it in debugger, what happens? You should! (MARS/SPIM simulators have reasonable debugging facilities). Why do you do `lw t6` + `move a0, t6`? You can load directly `a0`. You don't reset `t4` between loops back to zero. The `sub $t0, $t0, 40` looks fragile to me, I would rather use `la $t0, arr` again, which will work even when you change amount of elements in array (less code to edit, still too much to my taste, including those `blt` .. I would rather create input and output subroutines taking as arguments array pointer and size, so you can reuse them for any arr).

Comment: And rather zero the `t4` ahead of first loop too. It's a bit fragile practice to rely on initial state of registers, which on many platforms may be not guaranteed (although I think MARS/SPIM will clear all of them ahead of starting your code always, but it irks me every time I read your source, I have reflex "uninitialized thing used" exercised...)